# Take id from index

Tags: c#, ravendb

I want to retrieve  `_document_id` from a ravendb index and I don't know how to do that. I try with `GetDocumentId()` but it's not work because index id is null and the reall `id` is in `_document_id`.

Comment: what do you want exactly to know? it's my first question, sorry if i not explain enough

Comment: Show your index code, how you query it and your desired output and me or someone else might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the document id in an index you can fetch it from the document metadata using **MetadataFor(object)** like this:

```
public class Customer_ByName : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Customer>
{
    public Customer_ByName()
    {
        Map = customers => from customer in customers
                            select new
                            {
                                Name = customer.Name,
                                DocumentId = MetadataFor(customer)["__document_id"]
                            };
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!